# bp register doesn't work in based index

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16

This is a code I've written to move data in a reverse order from one array to another.

```
data segment
arr1 db 10h,20h,30h,40h
arr2 db 4 dup(0)
cnt dw 04h
data ends
code segment
assume cs:code,ds:data
start: mov ax,data
mov ds,ax
lea si,arr1
lea di,arr2
mov cx,cnt
mov bp,cx
mov bx,00h
back:
mov dl,[si][bx]
mov [di+bp-1],dl
dec bp
```

This line of code above ( the `bp` register) is not loading the memory I wish to address with the based index addressing.

```
inc bx
loop back
mov ah,4ch
int 21h
code ends
end start
```

Comment: The bp register addresses memory with the ss register.  Consider the REP MOVS instruction.

Comment: Please be consistent in how you address memory! If you use `mov [di+bp-1],dl` then also use `mov dl,[si+bx]` instead of hopping to `[si][bx]`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may have to prefix the indexed address by `ds:`, since the default segment for `bp` indexed addresses is the stack segment `ss`.

```
mov ds:[bp+di-1], dl
```

Comment: Worth pointing out that in 16-bit addressing modes, `di` can't be the base register, only an index (and `bp/bx` can only be base regs).  So `[di + bp]` is actually encoded as `[bp + di]`, with `bp` as the base implying `ss` as the segment.  In a 32-bit addressing mode, both `[ebp + edi]` (implicitly `ss`) and `[edi + ebp]` (implicitly `ds`) are encodeable.